# При выполнении session_start(); почему вылазит предупреждение

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

Почему при выполнии через **Ajax** запрос следующего кода с **session_start();** не работает **echo** и вобще скрипт по идеи выдаёт ошибку

php код:

```
session_start();

include "mysqlConnect.php";

$name = iconv("utf-8","windows-1251",$_POST['name']);
$name = trim($name);
$name = stripslashes($name);
$name = htmlspecialchars ($name);


$pass = iconv("utf-8","windows-1251",$_POST['pass']);
$pass = trim($pass);
$pass = stripslashes($pass);
$pass = htmlspecialchars ($pass);



$sql = mysqli_query ($db, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE firstname='".$name."' AND pass='".$pass."'");

$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($sql);

if ($num_rows > 0) {

    $arr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
    $_SESSION['id'] = $arr['id'];
    $_SESSION['firstname'] = $arr['firstname'];
    $_SESSION['lastname'] = $arr['lastname'];
    echo "0";
    }

else {
    echo "1";
    }

?>
```

JS код:

```
/*Кнопка входа*/
    var clickButtonLoginForm = $(".clickButtonLoginForm"); // Делаем выборку кнопки из DOM дерева и заносим её в переменную
    clickButtonLoginForm.click(function(){

        var name_login = $("#name_login").val();
        var pass_login = $("#pass_login").val();

        if (name_login == "" || pass_login == "") {

            $("#error").text("Вы не заполнили все поля").removeClass("success").addClass("error").show().delay(3000).fadeOut(300);

        } else {

            $.ajax({

                url: "action_login.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {name: name_login, pass: pass_login},
                success: function(data){

                    if (data) {

                        if (data == 1) {

                            alert("Такая пара логин/пароль НЕ найдена.");

                        } else {

                            if (data == 0) {

                                alert("Вы успешно авторизовались. Обновите страницу (F5).");

                            } else {

                                alert("Неизвестная ошибка");

                            }

                        }

                    } else {

                        alert("Данные не получены!!!");

                    }

                },
                error: function(){

                    alert("Неизвестная ошибка, возможно отсутсвует подлючение к интернету");

                }

            });

        }

    });
```

Comment: и какая же ошибка?

Comment: Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at **\action_login.php:1) in **\action_login.php on line 2

Comment: Почему вылазит предупреждение?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас до строчки  session_start() выводиться где то разметка, а это заголовок, поэтому и выводиться предупреждение.  Перенесите session_start до начала вывода html разметки. Так же возможно пробел добавляется кодировкой для unix систем, в этом случае перекодируйте ваш php файл в кодировку utf 8 without bom, например через notepad++

Comment: Он самый первый

Comment: дописал, ответ - прочитайте последнее предложение.

Comment: Добавил @ всё норм